# Importing Clusters In MAAS Ubuntu Cloud

Tags: ubuntu, cloud

i'm trying to download the clusters in MAAS Ubuntu Cloud , i had waited for more than 10 min

"The region controller does not know whether any boot images have been imported yet. If this message does not disappear in 5 minutes, there may be a communication problem between the region worker process and the region controller. Check the region worker's logs for signs that it was unable to report to the MAAS API."

could you please help me to resolve this problem

i am accessing the ubuntu cloud from virtual machine and windows 8 is my host machine , i am new to this filed please tell me where did it went wrong

Comment: hey here is the pic for my cloud

http://i.stack.imgur.com/KR5Zs.png

Comment: On Ubuntu Server 14.04


1) Configure a static address for the network adapter in /etc/network/interfaces

# Example configuration
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.2
        network 192.168.0.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1

continution is below comment

Comment: 2) Check internet access by pinging an external host, e.g. ping google.com.
The entry gateway 192.168.0.1 is essential, as it will establish a route, like sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1

3) Reconfigure MAAS to that static address and import PXE images: How to change the MaaS server ip address?

sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller
Delete 'Cluster master' (will be recreated)
4) Import PXE images

sudo maas-import-pxe-files

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu Server 14.04

1) Configure a static address for the network adapter in /etc/network/interfaces

## Example configuration

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

```
    address 192.168.0.2
    network 192.168.0.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

2) Check internet access by pinging an external host, e.g. ping google.com.

The entry gateway 192.168.0.1 is essential, as it will establish a route, like

sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1

3) Reconfigure MAAS to that static address and import PXE images:

How to change the MaaS server ip address?

sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller

sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller

Delete 'Cluster master' (will be recreated)

4) Import PXE images

sudo maas-import-pxe-files